# Android Applications: hard code data vs prewritten sqllite database

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite

I am writing an Android Application that is used for studying regulations.  The application will read data from a database of 1000 questions and randomly select 20 questions for the practice exam.  I have hard coded the information into the application (example below):

Question q99=new Question("Cell phones / portable electronic devices may only be used in the presence of trainees when: ", "They can be used at any time", "Both C and D", "a training requirement warrents it", "in an emergency situation", "Both C and D", "Para 4.6.9.3.2.");//B

this.addQuestion(q99);

The constructor format is: Question("Question", "AnswerA", "AnswerB", "AnswerC", "AnswerD", "CorrectAnswer", "Reference");

As you can see, adding each question to the database is resulting in over 2000 lines of code just to populate the database.

Do I need to keep this in the final publish of the application, or should I just write the database separately and include the database in the final release.

DJ

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to keep this in the final publish of the application, or should I just write the database separately and include the database in the final release.

I would go with the latter approach, [coupled with `SQLiteAssetHelper` for packaging that database with the app](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). It should be faster for the first launch of the app, as copying a file from assets should be faster than running a bunch of `INSERT` statements in a transaction. It also gives you possible flexibility of how to build up the database (e.g., build it using some desktop tool), rather than having to hand-code it in Java.